# Solr join best approach

Tags: solr, lucene, nosql

I have a scenario where I have a productdatabase in solr and a branddatabase in MySql. In the solr productdatabase I have a field named brandid where I refer to the Mysql primary key from the branddatabase. Now I would like to join the branddatabase for each solr searchquery and groups the result seperatly from the product results. I thought about a second solr database where I save the branddata and then join it on every query, but I would like to have each brand only one time and not merged together with the product results in the same resultset. A facette-style result for the brands is my goal. Anyone has a pointer how I could achieve this kind of results in my xml/json?

The resultset how I would like to have it in pseudo solr code:

```
<results>
    <products>
        <product>
            ...
        </product>
        <product>
            ...
        </product>
        <product>
            ...
        </product>
        <product>
            ...
        </product>
    </products>
    <brands>
        <brand>
            ...
        </brand>
        <brand>
            ...
        </brand>
    </brands>
</results>
```

Comment: No offense but, did you read the question?

Comment: Do you need to apply any query filters/fields from the brand database or it's used just for resolution of brand names?

Comment: I need a few fields, so brand is not only the name. It should also serv the link to the brand etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you only need to serve additional fields from brand database and you do not need to search/filter on them then you could apply a simple faceting on `brandid` and populate the presentation fields in a post processing step from DB directly/memory cache/key value store...
and use `facet.mincount=1` to eliminate the brands without any products in the current query.

Comment: I'd agree, if you only want a field on the right/left showing brand information about the found products, you should use faceting over joining. You could even consider to push all relevant information of the brands into the index, if that does not over increase your index size.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a higher-level language?

I currently do something similar, but I use Java as the glue. The Java application takes in requests, goes against solr using solrj, retrieves all the results, including the facets, I take that response and query against mysql to get more information, I merge all the data in the java layer and then construct the xml/json response.

[solrj](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj)

other higher-level languages are offered:

[Ruby,PHP,Java,Scala,Python,.Net,Perl,Javascript](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/IntegratingSolr)